# Google Drive Android API Change Notifications not working

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am using Google Drive Android API sample and in that sample i am able to create file and folder in Drive but if i want to monitor change events for a file which is cretaed by this app then it is not working.

https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos in this sample there is one activity to receive notfiications for change event in a file, which is not working.

I am not seeing any notification when i changed metadata of selected file from web.

Answer (score 1):

Changes from the web are not instantaneously reflected on the device.  You will get notified when the device finds out about the change.

You can speed up that process by calling requestSync.

Comment: In Google drive API for android it is not mentioned to use requestSync and it also requires GoogleAccountManager which is not available in this API.

Comment: I don't understand about GoogleAccountManager. The 'requestSync' in question is the 'Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(GoogleApiClient)", right?

Comment: Correct, requestSync referred to Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(GoogleApiClient)