# Android Google Drive API, file Change Notifications not working

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am working on google drive api, I am using https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos but not getting notification.
I am not seeing any notification when I changed metadata of selected file from web.
Does anyone succeeded, please provide a link or demo so that a hurdle can be remove.

I have checked similar question [Google Drive Android API Change Notifications not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980497/google-drive-android-api-change-notifications-not-working?rq=1), as I am unable to comment on this question due to less reputation.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use change listeners to receive notifications whenever a specified file or folder has changes to its contents or metadata.

Based from [Google Drive API for Androids on how to listen for change events](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/events):

> A change listener implements the `OnChangeListener` interface for the
>   `ChangeEvent` and receives a direct callback from the Drive service to a
>   currently connected client application.

You can add a change listener by calling the `DriveResourceClient.addChangeListener` method, passing in the file or folder you want to receive notifications for.

```
getDriveResourceClient()
        .addChangeListener(file, changeListener)
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, listenerToken -> mChangeListenerToken = listenerToken);
```

Comment: I am using <https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos>, it is having same code which you provided. problem is I am no getting notifications after I am changing file from web.